Second monitor with Ubuntu 24.04 and nVidia Quadro T1000
This is actually my first post! I am quite new to linux. I have a hp Zbook with a nVidia Quadro T1000 and I have installed Ubunutu 24.04. LTS. So far everything work, but now I realized that cannot use a second monitor via HDMI.
The command xrandr gives me the following output:
>  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
> DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI-0
> disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP-1 connected
> primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm
> x 194mm    1920x1080     60.06*+  40.04   DP-2 disconnected (normal
> left inverted right x axis y axis) None-1-1 connected (normal left
> inverted right x axis y axis)    1920x1080     60.00 +

I would appreciate any help!
Edit 1: I have tried three different HDMI cables and two different monitors. All combination did not work. For another laptop (Windows) all combination worked.

Have you tired a different HDMI cable and or a different monitor. Your error post says that there is nothing connected to the the HDMI port.

@David Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have tried 3 different HDMI cables and 2 different monitors. All cables/monitors work with other laptops (windows).

Please edit the question and add these details. Any answer is only as good as the info given.

I have modified the question accordingly.
